# Php send 65 Ascii char to socket

Tags: php, sockets, tcp, ip, ascii

Im trying to send a 65 ascii char to a device Im reading from via php sockets. I need to reply to confirm the info has been received.

I have tried the following with no joy:

```
$ascii = ord("A"); // 65    
socket_write($spawn, $ascii, strlen ($ascii)) or die("Could not write output\n");
```

is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're sending the string `"65"`, not a single byte with that value. You can do:

```
socket_write($spawn, chr(65), 1) or die("Could not write output\n");
```